# Syntax with qreal reference as a parameter

Tags: c++, qt, reference, parameters

I'm using Qt with C++ and I don't seem to understand something that feels inconsistent to me.
I have a method that manipulates the variables that are sent to it as parameters, here is its declaration `aManipulation(qreal& a); //reference to a qreal`

I use `QPointF` which contains two qreal values. The class can return a qreal value through a method, or a reference qreal& through another method. So I'm curious about these cases:

```
qreal value = 1;
QPointF point; point.setX(1);

//OK -- this works eventhough I don't send it as a qreal&
aManipulation(value);

//FAIL -- actually trying to send a qreal& reference is an error
aManipulation(value&);

//OK -- this method however returns a qreal&
aManipulation(point.rx());

//FAIL -- this just returns the '1' and I understand it cannot be referenced
aManipulation(point.x());
```

Why is it enough to send the object and not a reference to the object to a method that wants a reference of an object? I am confused as doing this with pure pointers would be very clear.

Comment: You always send it as a reference if the function takes it as a reference. There's no special syntax involved.

Comment: So when I try to send aManipulation(value&); I'm actually trying to send a reference to a reference, causing the fail?

Comment: `aManipulation(value&);` is not real syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass 'value' to:

```
aManipulation(qreal& value)
{
}
```

by saying:

```
qreal myreal = 1.2;
aManimulation(myreal);
```

the compiler actually passes a *reference* to myreal, there's no need to say 'myreal&' (in fact, you can't).

Passing pointers may seem clearer, but the reference approach is safer. You still get the benefit of passing an address to something - instead of the whole something - without the risk of the pointer being modified.

I think the code's cleaner too. You don't have all the '*' or the need for putting 'const' in the right place to keep the *pointer* from being modified while still allowing what it points to be.

When I look at my old code with all the pointers being passed around, it looks pretty ugly to me, but that's subjective. Of course there are times you actually want to pass pointer (or pointers to pointers).

Comment: Okay, I see. Can you explain how does this method of `QPointF` work when sending it as a parameter that shoould be a reference? `qreal & QPointF::rx ()` If I understand correctly, this returns a reference but as you just said you shouldn't be able to send it as a parameter.

Comment: I see what your saying. OK, you can't send 'value&' as a parameter, but you can send 'value'. So yes, QPoint::rx() returns a reference - which is kind of unusual, but allows you to modify the value - and that reference simply gets passed on to your method that takes a reference. In the other case - passing a value - the compiler will convert it to a reference in the function call.  I think the point of confusion is that with 'by reference' parameters, you never have to say 'value&' - assuming the argument is legal (ie qreal or even int, which gets cast to qreal), the compiler will make a ref.